# Swift AsyncStream iteration waiting till end

Tags: swift, async-await

I'm trying to test out some async stream but I'm not sure I am understanding them correctly. I have the following two example functions:

```
func foo() async throws {
    print("Start")
    for await data in bar() {
        print(data)
    }
    print("End")
}

private func bar() -> AsyncStream<String> {
    return AsyncStream { continuation in
        print("Stream Started")
        for count in 0...2 {
            sleep(1)
            print("Yielding...")
            continuation.yield("\(count)")
        }
        continuation.finish()
    }
}
```

I would have expected this to print something like this:

```
Start
Stream Started
Yielding...
0
Yielding...
1
Yielding...
2
End
```

However what I am seeing is:

```
Start
Stream Started
Yielding...
Yielding...
Yielding...
0
1
2
End
```

Is my expectation wrong here on how this stream should work?

Comment: At least never ever `sleep` this antique way. You undermine the async functionality. There is a native non-blocking way to wait for a moment.

Comment: @vadian appears that was the cause. My antique coding skills caused the problem :-)

Comment: The more interesting and much more subtle question is, how would the console log look like, if you would remove `sleep()` or the corrected version with `Task.sleep(for:)`. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 kinds of `sleep`, one for the thread (you are using this one)

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/thread/1413673-sleep

and the one that must be used in concurrency.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/task/sleep(_:)

```
private func bar() -> AsyncStream<String> {
    return AsyncStream { continuation in
        let task = Task{
            print("Stream Started")
            for count in 0...2 {
                //Concurrency version of sleeping
                try await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(1))
                print("Yielding...")
                continuation.yield("\(count)")
            }
            continuation.finish()
        }
        continuation.onTermination = { _ in
            //Make sure you cancel the task if the stream is terminated 
            task.cancel()
        }
    }
}
```

Concurrency isn't directly related to threads, it is more about "Actors"

https://developer.apple.com/wwdc21/10132